# Copying GitHub repo to new remote URL

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a GitHub repo that I want to copy and push to a new remote URL under a different organization. I'd like to preserve as much history as possible, such as branches and commits, but I'm not sure how to do this. My local copy doesn't have all branches.

I've seen similar questions, but I wanted to confirm since it's somewhat of a risky task.

Are the steps something like this?

`git fetch origin`

`git branch -a`

`git remote add new-origin git@github.com:user/repo.git`

`git push --all new-origin`

`git push --tags new-origin`

`git remote -v`

`git remote rm origin`

`git remote rename new-origin origin`

Comment: Why not clone it on GitHub?

Comment: @SLaks Clone and then what? I've already cloned it locally, but I want to preserve the history

Comment: Sorry; I meant fork it

Comment: @SLaks I thought about that too, but I want the new repo to be independent from the original since it'll get deleted later

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to keep both endpoints you could do `git remote set-url --add origin https://new.url/path/to/repo.git` and this will make it so when you push, you will push to both endpoints at the same time. However pulling only comes from one source. If pulling is a concern then I recommend using a new remote. Your steps are similar to the ones you previous mentioned:

To push your current history to a new endpoint, completely unrelated to the current endpoint, follow these steps. Note that this will disconnect your local repository from the current endpoint and join it to your new endpoint.

1) `git pull --all`

2) `git pull -t` or `git pull --tags`

3) `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git`

4) `git push --all`

5) `git push --tags`

and if anything goes wrong, all you need to do is clone from your original repo.git that origin is currently set to

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your steps were right. But pay attention on below:

1. For the first step, you can use `git pull` instead (pull function is fetch + merge).
2. After finish the steps what you mentioned, you will only find the branches of the first repo (not the new URL). Use `git branch –a`, you will find all the branches of first repo and new URL repo on remote.
3. You need to create local branches to track on remote correspondingly. Such as `git checkout –b branch_name1 origin/branch_name1`, `git checkout –b branch_name2 origin/branch_name2` etc.
4. Now you will find the local copy has both branches for first repo and branches for new URL, and the commit history is preserved.